# Issue after DB2 upgrade to 10.5

Tags: java, db2

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.64.96] Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB_105\BIN\db2jcct2.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:663) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:94) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.a.a(a.java:37) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t2.T2Configuration.<clinit>(T2Configuration.java:95) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:436) 
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:116) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Operating system , db2level , registry , db2jcc.jar , db2jcct2.dll is of 64 bit.

Even tough the above all are of 64 bit , it is still pointing to 32 bit.

In the application , it is no where pointing to 32 bit.

Can you please let us know how it is pointing to 32 bit.

Comment: What is the java-version you are using to run your application? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: The Java version used in the application is of 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the Type 2 driver, which requires a native CLI library and which was discontinued in DB2 10.1. You will need to convert your application to use the Type 4 driver, as [described in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0058719.html).

Comment: The JCC driver (which OP is using) has both Type 2 and Type 4 modes; the Type 2 functionality is very much supported. You're thinking of the old "app" driver, com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver, right?

Comment: Ian , the Driver I am referring to is com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.

Comment: It's the URL format that enables one functionality or the other.